# Looping through httpcache c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net-to-c#

On VB.NET I can do things like this to write out all the keys in the cache:

```
Dim oc As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current

For Each c As Object In oc.Cache
    oc.Response.Write(c.Key.ToString())
Next
```

Although the .Key doesn't come up in Intellisense the code works just fine.

How do I do the same in c#?

```
HttpContext oc = HttpContext.Current;
foreach (object c in oc.Cache) 
{
    oc.Response.Write(c.key.ToString());
}
```

It doesn't like the .key. bit.  I'm at a loss here.  Any ideas how to access the key in this way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below code snap is working fine:

```
HttpContext oc = HttpContext.Current;
foreach (var c in oc.Cache)        
{
   oc.Response.Write(((DictionaryEntry)c).Key.ToString());
}
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 11):

Almost right - it's a capital `K` for `Key`, not lower case. C# is case sensitive.

Additionally, `object` doesn't have a `Key` member. In C# you can use implicit type inference with the [`var`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) keyword as well. This will work if the underlying inferred type has a `Key` member:

```
HttpContext oc = HttpContext.Current;

foreach (var c in oc.Cache) 
{
    oc.Response.Write(c.Key.ToString());
}
```

In this case, `Cache` doesn't have a `Key` member, so you need to dig deeper, using the `IDictionaryEnumerator` returned by the `GetEnumerator` method of `Cache`:

```
HttpContext oc = HttpContext.Current;

IDictionaryEnumerator en = oc.Cache.GetEnumerator();
while(en.MoveNext())
{
    oc.Response.Write(en.Key.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I can't get that to work for me, still doesn't compile and still complains about the .Key despite changing to var in the foreach and .Key uppercase.  "Error 6 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: OK I think I have figured it out. I can do the same by this approach:

        IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = oc.Cache.GetEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            oc.Response.Write(enumerator.Key.ToString());
        }

Comment: Sorry is the @downvoter at me? The reason I marked the correct answer with a tick is that your answer was initially incorrect.  When I pointed this out you corrected it (10.54) but it still wasn't a working answer.  I then found out an answer myself from a google search and posted it as a comment (11.05).  You then adjusted your answer without crediting that.  So in summary, your answer was wrong, hadn't been tested and you only got the right answer when you copied it from me.  It's great that you give lots of answers but unless you are accurate, it's not much use. Hope this feedback helps.